# Infinite sum of analytic functions becomes non-analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

I am looking for a simple example that a series of analytic functions can become non-analytic. This is in the context of phase transitions, where one considers the analyticity of the partition function which may show singular behaviour in infinitely large systems, signaling a phase transition …

Many thanks!

Comment: The [Weierstrass nowhere differentiable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is the (pointwise) sum of functions of the form $A\cos(kx)$ and [every continuous function with compact domain](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassApproximationTheorem.html) is the (uniform) sum of polynomial functions.

Comment: You may want to ask a more precise question. Do you want the sum to be convergent everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f_n(z)=z^n$.

$f_n(z)$ is an entire function for every integer $n\ge0$.

However, $$\sum^\infty_{k=0}f_k(z)$$ only converges for $|z|<1$. In other words, this sum of entire functions is not analytic outside the unit disk.